# Using min and max in one select statement (buggy output?)

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to pull min and max values from a csv file as part of my homework, but when I run my code, the column name is printed instead of the actual max value, whilst the min prints just fine.

I've tried separating into different select statements, like separating both min and max, but that didn't work. That statement is fine to print the total number in the table, the average age, and min balance. But failed to print the max limit balance. Can I not combine min and max in one statement? It does look like for the second set of parentheses, it printed out fine, the max being 1,000,000 for that column in my CSV.

This is the table structure for what I'm trying to do, lists the names of the columns for the table.

```
c.execute(                                                   
    '''CREATE TABLE Users (ID INTEGER, LIMIT_BAL INTEGER, SEX 
    INTEGER, EDUCATION INTEGER, MARRIAGE INTEGER,
    AGE INTEGER, PAY_0 INTEGER, PAY_2 INTEGER, PAY_3 INTEGER, PAY_4 INTEGER, PAY_5 INTEGER,
    PAY_6 INTEGER, BILL_AMT1 INTEGER, BILL_AMT2 INTEGER, BILL_AMT3 INTEGER, BILL_AMT4 INTEGER,
    BILL_AMT5 INTEGER,BILL_AMT6 INTEGER, PAY_AMT1 INTEGER, PAY_AMT2 INTEGER, PAY_AMT3 INTEGER,
    PAY_AMT4 INTEGER, PAY_AMT5 INTEGER, PAY_AMT6 INTEGER, default_payment_next_month INTEGER)
    ''')

# sixth query
c.execute(
    'SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(AGE), MIN(LIMIT_BAL), MAX(LIMIT_BAL) \
    default_payment_next_month FROM Users GROUP BY 
    default_payment_next_month = 0')
rows = c.fetchall()
print('6): \n', rows)
```

output:

```
6): 
[(6319, 35.645830036398166, 10000, 'LIMIT_BAL'), (21752, 35.39196395733725, 10000, 1000000)]
```

Comment: Your query does not make any sense.  Please provide table structure for `Users`, and also show us sample input and output data.

Comment: The input is the sixth query part. All I'm trying to do is have the maximum limit_balance from the actual table show in the output print statement.

Comment: OK...what is the meaning of `default_payment_next_month = 0`?  What is this supposed to be doing?

Comment: Count the # records, average AGE, min LIMIT_BAL, max LIMIT_BAL for default.payment.next.month=0 (no default) vs. default.payment.next.month=1 (default), using GROUP BY; That's what i'm supposed to do. So the rows in the default.payment.next.month column only have 0s and 1s. So I'm assuming that I'd have to take the avg age/count/min balance and max for the rows that have 0s and 1s, if that makes sense.

Comment: If `0` and `1` be the _only_ values which `default_payment_next_month` can take, then your `GROUP BY` clause should be `GROUP BY default_payment_next_month`.

Comment: Okay that would make sense, so I should probably delete the default_payment_next_month = 0 part right? How about splitting it up by having the avg age/count/min/max for 0s and then the same for 1s? I think that's what the =0 part is for

Answer (score 0):

The query I would try is

SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(AGE), MIN(LIMIT_BAL), MAX(LIMIT_BAL)
 FROM Users 
    where default_payment_next_month = 0
    GROUP BY default_payment_next_month

I am not sure what the statement MAX(LIMIT_BAL) \ default_payment_next_month is doing. I have made the assumption that you are dividing MAX(LIMIT_BAL) by default_payment_next_month. If that is the case then the statement is MAX(LIMIT_BAL) / default_payment_next_month but this probably won't work in the group by.